# How can I obtain Final Fantasy Adventure for a mobile phone in the US?

Tags: final-fantasy-adventure

A little backstory: The first (quasi) RPG I ever played was *Final Fantasy Adventure*. At that time, I was quite the platformer fan, and NES Zelda games, although moderately fun, never caught my attention for long.

One day at a flea market, I picked up *Final Fantasy Adventure* for a couple bucks, and I fell in love with the experience of leveling up, weapon selection, and getting engaged in the story. I was hooked, and from then on I was a hardcore RPGer*.

Because of its personal history, *FFA* has a special place in my gaming heart. Every few years, I pull out my old cart, slap it in my old-school GB, and play it for a few hours. It doesn't matter where my saved file is—I've practically memorized what to do from any place in the game, and it's always just as enjoyable as its initial discovery.

Today, I learned that back in 2006, a Japanese version was released for mobile phones that was quite similar to the original but with updated graphics. As an uber-fan... I MUST PLAY THIS GAME.

Sorry, I'm still a bit excited. The problem is that I live in the US, and I would have no clue how to obtain a mobile game from an international market. Can this be done? Is there an emulator for such a thing, and if so, where can I find it? I don't mind that the game's text will be in Japanese. I can't read it, but, honestly, I don't have to.

Yes, I get it. I'm a bit of an obsessive nerd.

<sup>* I know that *FFA* isn't a typical RPG. However, it did have RPG elements, and it led me to other games in the FF storyline. I fell in love with the traditional RPG style as much as I did with the Action-RPG style of *FFA*, and I've never looked back.</sup>

Comment: Secret of Mana and Seikendensetsu 3 are the next two games in the series, if you weren't aware.  FFA was not actually a Final Fantasy game.  (I don't know how to make links in a comment?)

Comment: @RentheUnclean To put a link in the comments, put the text to link in a square brackets and the link immediately after in parentheses. <code>[text](link)</code>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the cellphone version, but you may be able to find copies of the Game Boy Advance version, [Sword of Mana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_Mana), which had an English release.

It incorporated many of the changes to later games in the series.

Speaking of the series, Final Fantasy Adventure is actually part of the "Seiken Densetsu" or "Mana" series of games.

It has 3 direct sequels:
Secret of Mana (SNES)
Seiken Densetsu 3 (Super Famicom, no US release)
Dawn of Mana (PS2)

It also has 4 spinoffs:
Legend of Mana (PS1), similar style to the second and third games.
Children of Mana (DS), a dungeon crawler
Heroes of Mana (DS), a tactical RPG
Friends of Mana (Mobile phone, no US release), no idea

Comment: There was also Secret of Evermore, made by a Square team based in the US. It is supposed to be a similar type of game to Secret of Mana.